# Selecting columns using variables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Probably not the best description for a title but I really couldn't think of anything.
What I want to happen is that I can create a query that selects the *type* from listings using the userID as a relationship and then selecting the town.

```
TABLE listings
saleID userID   type          description
1      23     clothing       nice clothing
2      45     clothing     More nice Clothing

TABLE users
userID    country      county         town
23         uk          county       townname1
24         uk          county       townname2
```

The variables are set in the url as a get eg) ?type=clothing&town=townname2

```
if (!isset($type)){
$query = "SELECT * FROM listings";
}
if (isset($type)) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE type = '{$type}'";
}
```

This is the bit i'm stuck on I want to get all listings with the variable $type '*clothing*' and then select from users with the town of the variable $town

```
if (isset($town)) {
   $query = "SELECT users.town listings.userID listings.type FROM listings 
   WHERE type = '{$type}' 
   INNER JOIN users 
   ON users.town = '{$town}'";       
}
```

Hope I've explained this well enough to understand.
Please help me with this last query

Comment: also validate input values for SQL injections, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.town l.userID, l.type 
FROM listings l
INNER JOIN users u on u.userID = l.userID   
WHERE l.type = '{$type}' 
AND u.town = '{$town}'
```

Comment: $results = mysql_query($query);

while ($listing = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {

Comment: sorry, i keep pressing enter, how do I access the description in TABLE listings? would I do $listings['l.description'] because it doesnt seem to find it ?

Comment: figured it out. needed it to be all instead of just specifying particular columns. CHANGED l.userID, l.type TO l.*  Thanks again for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.town, a.userID, a.type 
FROM    listings a
        INNER JOIN users b 
            ON  a.userID  = b.userID    
WHERE   a.type = '{$type}' AND
        b.town = '{$town}'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm assuming the "a" is acting as a variable for listings? "FROM    listings **a**"